# How to redirect and show validation messages back to a partial view when Model.isvalid is false in ASP.NET MVC

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, validation, asp.net-mvc-4

I'm trying to show the validation messages back to a partial view when a model is validated against a model class.But when failed I don't know how to display the validation error message back to the VIEW  from where the POST is fired
This is code of  partial view ( _CreateCustomer )

```
 @model Banking.Models.Customer
 @Html.ValidationSummary(true)

<fieldset>
    @using (Html.BeginForm("CreateCustomer", "Customer",FormMethod.Post))
        {
            @Html.ValidationSummary(true)

    <div id="cusCreate">
        <table id="createCustomer">
            <tr><td>Please enter ther details of the Customer </td></tr>
            <tr>
                <td>First Name : </td>
                <td>
                    @Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.FirstName)
                    @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.FirstName)
                </td>
                <td>Last Name : </td>
                <td>
                    @Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.LastName)
                    @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.LastName)
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Address : </td>
                <td>
                    @Html.TextAreaFor(model => model.Address)
                    @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Address)
                </td>
                <td>City : </td>
                <td>
                    @Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.City)
                    @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.City)
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>State : </td>
                <td>
                    @Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.State)
                    @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.State)
                </td>
                <td>Pincode :</td>
                <td>
                    @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Pincode)
                    @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Pincode)
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Phone : </td>
                <td>
                    @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Phone)
                    @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Phone)
                </td>
                <td>Email :</td>
                <td>
                    @Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.Email)
                    @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Email)
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td style="align-content:center" colspan="4"> </td>
            </tr>
        </table>
        <input type="submit" value="CreateCustomer" id="cusSubBtn" />
    </div>

    }
</fieldset>
```

Following is the code of view where the partial view is loaded

```
@{
    ViewBag.Title = "CustomerMain";
    Layout = "~/Views/Shared/_Layout.cshtml";
}

@Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jquery")
<html>
<head>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function () {
            $('#CusCreatebtn').click(function (event) {
                $("#CusDynamicPortion").hide();
                $("#CusDynamicPortion").load("/Customer/CreateCustomerData");
                $("#CusDynamicPortion").show();
            });
        });
    </script>
</head>
<body >
    <div id="CusDynamicPortion">
        <table id="customeroptions" style="width:100%">
            <tr>
                <td><input type="button" id="CusCreatebtn" value="Add New Customer" /> </td>
                <td><input type="button" id="CusViewbtn" value="View Customer" /> </td>
            </tr>
        </table>

    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Code of the corresponding controller class (Customer.cs)

```
public ActionResult CreateCustomerData()
{
    return PartialView("_CreateCustomer");
}

[HttpPost]
public ActionResult CreateCustomer(Models.Customer model)
{
    if (ModelState.IsValid)
    {
        string firstName = model.FirstName;
        int pinCode = model.Pincode;
        return Content("Customer first name is " + firstName);
    }
    else
    {
        return RedirectToAction("index");
    }
}
```

Comment: Why are you not just including the `Customer` form in the main view. What is the point of using `.load()` and losing client side validation as well?

Comment: Provide the name of `HttpPost` method also `CreateCustomerData` and then Try `return PartialView(model)` within else part of the `if(ModelState.IsValid)`

Comment: How about including some javascript in the PartialView that will display the error message. The javascript is executed only if the relevant Viewbag item is specified, and this viewbag item can be initialized only if the model is invalid (ModelState.IsValid = false).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you save your form your site does POST request which looks like this:

```
POST http://localhost:62186/Customer/CreateCustomer HTTP/1.1
FirstName=&LastName=&Address=&City=&State=&Pincode=&Phone=&Email=
```

When your code knows that `Model.IsValid` is false then it uses `RedirectToAction` method which sends 302 HTTP Response with redirect to /Customer address. Then browser does GET request like this:

```
GET http://localhost:62186/Customer HTTP/1.1
```

As you can see, your request data are completely lost. First thing you need to do is to replace `RedirectToAction` with `View` method with pointing to your parent view. It will load your view in context of POST request. This is how your POST action should look like:

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult CreateCustomer(Models.Customer model)
{
    if (ModelState.IsValid)
    {
        string firstName = model.FirstName;
        int pinCode = model.Pincode;
        return Content("Customer first name is " + firstName);
    }
    else
    {
        return View("Index");
    }
}
```

When your view is rendered after POST request and you click "Add New Customer" then another GET request is performed and parameters are lost:

```
GET http://localhost:62186/Customer/CreateCustomerData HTTP/1.1
```

The best way to avoid this error is to prerender your partial view inside your parent view. You can use `Html.Partial` method which load a partial view into another view. Then you can surround this declaration with div element and use JavaScript to hide it and show. Your parent view should look like this:

```
@{
    ViewBag.Title = "CustomerMain";
    Layout = "~/Views/Shared/_Layout.cshtml";
}

@Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jquery")
<html>
<head>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function () {
            $("#CusForm").hide();
            $('#CusCreatebtn').click(function (event) {
                $("#CusForm").show();
            });
        });
    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="CusDynamicPortion">

        <div id="CusForm">
            @Html.Partial("_CreateCustomer")
        </div>

        <table id="customeroptions" style="width:100%">
            <tr>
                <td><input type="button" id="CusCreatebtn" value="Add New Customer" /> </td>
                <td><input type="button" id="CusViewbtn" value="View Customer" /> </td>
            </tr>
        </table>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

With this two fixes your code will work. But if you want to use AJAX to load and send form then you should read something about Ajax.BeginForm helper method.